# How to remove and re-fetch all git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I need to write a script that fetches all new changes in the repo, including updates in submodules and checks them out.

The problem is that submodules, as well as the main repo, may have commits that were "forced" (so they may have a conflicting tree). How do I re-fetch all submodules without getting any errors in the process and without purging and gecloning the main repo?